# Different build rules for different CUDA versions?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I'd like to specify in my CUDA code whether I'm compiling using CUDA build rule version 4.2 or CUDA build rule version 5.

Is there any macro used for such purpose?

Note: I know there is an option to specify whether current compilation process support certain architecture, e.g. `__CUDA_ARCH__`.

I'm looking for a similar macro for CUDA build rule version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The macro used for determining the CUDA Toolkit version is `CUDART_VERSION`

You can do conditional compilation of your code according to the CUDA Toolkit version like this:

```
#if CUDART_VERSION == 5000

//Compilation is being done using CUDA Toolkit 5.0

#elif CUDART_VERSION == 4200

//Compilation is being done using CUDA Toolkit 4.2
.
.
.
//And so on
#else

#endif
```